# Split up grouped binomial data in r

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have data that looks like this

```
samplesize <- 6

group <- c(1,2,3)
total <- rep(samplesize,length(group))
outcomeTrue <- c(2,1,3)

df <- data.frame(group,total,outcomeTrue)
```

and would like my data to look like this

```
group2 <- c(rep(1,6),rep(2,6),rep(3,6))
outcomeTrue2 <- c(rep(1,2),rep(0,6-2),rep(1,1),rep(0,6-1),rep(1,3),rep(0,6-3))

df2 <- data.frame(group2,outcomeTrue2)
```

That is to say I have binary data where I am told the total observations and the successful observations, but would prefer it to be organised as individual observations with their explicit outcome as 0 or 1. i.e.[Visual Example of Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP2M7.png)

Is there an easy way to do this in r, or will I need to write a loop to automate this myself?

Comment: `outcomeTrue` and `outcomeTrue2` should be `outcome` and `outcome2`, respectively.

Comment: you're right, so sorry, changed one but forgot to change the other.

Comment: No, problem. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option with `tidyverrse`.  We `uncount` to expand the rows using the 'total' column, grouped by 'group', create a binary index with a logical condition based on the `row_number()` and the value of 'outcomeTrue'

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   uncount(total) %>% 
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(outcomeTrue = as.integer(row_number() <= outcomeTrue[1]))
# A tibble: 18 x 2
# Groups:   group [3]
#   group outcomeTrue
#   <dbl>       <int>
# 1     1           1
# 2     1           1
# 3     1           0
# 4     1           0
# 5     1           0
# 6     1           0
# 7     2           1
# 8     2           0
# 9     2           0
#10     2           0
#11     2           0
#12     2           0
#13     3           1
#14     3           1
#15     3           1
#16     3           0
#17     3           0
#18     3           0
```

Answer (score 1):

You are also there. just use the group 2 variable with the "[" function in the x position:

```
df[ group2 , ]
    group total outcomeTrue
1       1     6           2
1.1     1     6           2
1.2     1     6           2
1.3     1     6           2
1.4     1     6           2
1.5     1     6           2
2       2     6           1
2.1     2     6           1
2.2     2     6           1
2.3     2     6           1
2.4     2     6           1
2.5     2     6           1
3       3     6           3
3.1     3     6           3
3.2     3     6           3
3.3     3     6           3
3.4     3     6           3
3.5     3     6           3
```

When a number or character value that matches a `rowname` is put in the x-position of the "[" it replicates the entire row

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$group), function(x) data.frame(group2 = x$group, outcome2 = rep(c(1,0), times = c(x$outcome, x$total-x$outcome)))))

#     group2 outcome2
# 1.1      1        1
# 1.2      1        1
# 1.3      1        0
# 1.4      1        0
# 1.5      1        0
# 1.6      1        0
# 2.1      2        1
# 2.2      2        0
# 2.3      2        0
# 2.4      2        0
# 2.5      2        0
# 2.6      2        0
# 3.1      3        1
# 3.2      3        1
# 3.3      3        1
# 3.4      3        0
# 3.5      3        0
# 3.6      3        0
```